# Image is not stored in Xcode

Tags: php, ios, xcode

I'm trying to upload an image in my first iPhone App but it's not working. I have followed some examples and tutorials but I still not getting it. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

The problem is that I'm getting the following errors:

- Your file is too large.
- When I check the name of the file it says: "http://www.example.com/images/.jpg" like it doesn't have a name.
- The image is not stored in /images/.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)uploadPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSLog(@"Photo enviada");

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 90);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://example.com/upload.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(returnString);
}
```

**Upload.php**

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/images/';      //Uploading to same directory as PHP file
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadFile = $file;
$randomNumber = rand(0, 99999); 
$newName = $uploadDir . $randomNumber . $uploadFile;


if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
} else {
    echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
}

if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']> 300000) {
    exit("Your file is too large."); 
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
    $postsize = ini_get('post_max_size');   //Not necessary, I was using these
    $canupload = ini_get('file_uploads');    //server variables to see what was 
    $tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');   //going wrong.
    $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    echo "http://www.example.com/images/{$file}" . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] ;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your file is too large.

The first thing in your script should be to set the max size

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 5M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 10M
```

> When I check the name of the file it says:
>   "http://www.example.com/images/.jpg" like it doesn't have a name.

Notice in your objective C code you did not put a name on this line `filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"`

> The image is not stored in /images/.

that's because you have an invalid path `$uploaddir = './images/';` should be:

```
$uploaddir = '/images/';
```

use this php:

```
<?php 
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])){ 
    echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";

    if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']> 300000) {
       exit("Your file is too large."); 
    }

    $uploaddir = "images/"; 
    $file = basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']); 
    $full_path = $uploaddir .$file; 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $full_path)) { 
        echo "http://www.autograpp.com/images/{$file}" . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] ;
    } else { 
        echo "upload received! but process failed"; 
    } 
}else{ 
    echo "upload failure ! temp was not uploaded"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks meda, the only problem I have now is that the image is not uploaded inside the folder /images/, it's stored in the same directory as the upload.php file. Why is this happening? Thanks again, much appreciated for your help. @meda

Comment: @JulienKP I adjusted the php for you

Comment: Much appreciated @meda, everything is working fine and the image is uploaded in the folder. Regards.